# How do i get The JLabel that i am using as a Background image to resize with the rest of the frame when i use the maximize button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

So I am Using the drag and drop function in netBeans and I have created a background using a JLabel icon, however when I maximize the window or even drag it to a bigger parameter the icon(background image stays the same size).

what can I do to fix this problem?
thank you.

Comment: It depends in the layout manager.Using `BorderLayout` and adding using `add(jLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);` might help.  Post an [MCVE] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Don't use a JLabel to do this as you add layers of complexity trying to re-size an ImageIcon. Instead, draw the image in the paintComponent method of a JPanel, one added BorderLayout.CENTER in your BorderLayout-using JFrame, and resize the image as per the duplicate question.

Comment: For other similar questions, and to see how to search for similar questions for your future problems, please see [this Google link that searches this site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+resize+background+image).